# Word for "unskippable"

Tags: english-to-german

In advertising, it is possible to have video adverts that are skippable and unskippable.

Skippable videos are those that give you a few seconds forced viewing, then allow you to skip the video if you are not interested.

How would I form such a sentence?

1. This video is not skippable.
2. This is an unskippable video.

Comment: http://www.dict.cc/?s=skippable

Comment: _Zwangswerbung, Pflichtvideo, Mussclip_ und entsprechende Adjektive oder Partizipien wie _zwingend, verpflichtend, vorgeschrieben, obligatorisch_ ‘mandatory’.

Comment: @Iris Dies ist einer dieser vielen Fälle, in denen ein wörtlich/wortweise übersetzter Satz kein besonders gutes Ergebnis liefert wie der Kommentar von @ Käsebrot mit der idiomatischen Floskel zeigt.

Comment: @Crissov, joa, der Hinweis auf bessere Wörter ist richtig (+1 für Zwangswerbung), aber das war nicht die Frage, oder?

Comment: @Iris Vom Titel her nicht, aber das Beispiel grenzt es schon ziemlich ein, weswegen ich auch gegen Schließen bin.

Comment: Die Werbung vor diesem Video kann man nicht überspringen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

skippable: überspringbar

unskippable: nicht überspringbar

1. Das Video ist [nicht] überspringbar.
2. Das ist ein [nicht] überspringbares Video.

Comment: I'm sorry. I miswrote the examples. I meant to ask for the word in a sentence for unskippable. However, you answered that question I think. Would "Das ist nicht ein überspringbares Video" work?

Comment: Imo, you would rather use the expressions: "Dieses Video kann übersprungen werden" or "Dieses Video kann nicht übersprungen werden". But this is just my opinion.

Comment: _unüberspringbar_ könnte man bilden, lässt es aber besser. Auch eher zu vermeiden wäre _Das ist **kein** überspringbares Video_.

Answer (score 0):

Das(this) ist(is) one(ein) unskippable (nicht überspringbares) Video